# unable to get validation if one of the field is empty and other is not empty using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to get validation for the form if one is filled and the other is empty then should get validation.If both fields are empty then should not get any validation.If one is filled with text and the other is empty then should get validation.I have tried with a code but it is not working.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="name"><b>Name</b><span class="mandatory">
                <font color="red">*</font>
            </span></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" class="mygroup">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="email"><b>Email</b><span class="mandatory">
                <font color="red">*</font>
            </span></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" class="mygroup">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <button id="submit" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>


$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('#uname').is(':filled');
            }
        }
    }
});

 });
```

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/actqp9y3/

Comment: Did you check your console for errors in that JSFiddle? You didn't include jQuery, and also had an old version of the validate plugin. https://jsfiddle.net/56tmsou1/ ...now it works fine with those dependencies sorted out. Nothing wrong with your code. Learn to check the console (and to debug in general), it'll give you a big clue as to what the problem is. If all you can tell us is "not working", it indicates that you haven't even begun to investigate it properly.

Comment: @ADyson if i give email id without giving name and click on submit its working fine it should not work

Comment: @ADyson if i add name and click on submit without adding email it should get validation or if i enter email and click on submit without giving name it should not work

Comment: "if i enter email and click on submit without giving name it should not work"... Should it not? You didn't write anything in the code to make a rule for that. So what did you expect? The code does what you told it to. It's not a bug, you just haven't finished the job. You need another rule for the uname to check if email is filled in or not. It should be easy - just the opposite of what you've got now, really. My point before was that your report of it not working was mainly because you didn't set the fiddle up properly.

Comment: @ADyson if i add name and click on submit it should not work it should show as fill the field and if i fill email and click on submit without filling name it shoud not work should show message as fill the name field

Comment: " if i add name and click on submit it should not work it should show as fill the field". You haven't written a rule for that, so what did you expect?

Comment: And ""if i enter email and click on submit without giving name it should not work". Again you haven't written a rule for that either.

Comment: The only rule you've implemented is "if I enter name and submit without filling email then it will show an error". Like I said, you just haven't finished the job. Have you got a problem in finishing it? The rules are really very simple.

Comment: @ADyson i have tired with that as well but it didnt work here is the fiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/2wvfkh5d/

Comment: The rules have to be all in one object. You're trying to define to separate validation setups on the same form. that won't work. Anyone would think there was no [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules) for this plugin...not to mention many tutorials too. Stop making it up as you go along and follow the examples properly instead.

Comment: Also that fiddle link you've just posted still has the same problems as your original - i.e. jquery not added, etc. So no matter what you write it will never work. Fork my version instead. And pay attention to your console!! It's not fun to keep repeating myself...

Comment: @ADyson can you please help me now i will g through it its little urgent please

Comment: I'm a volunteer. If you want "urgent" please find someone to pay to work for you. Your time is not more valuable than mine. I find that very cheeky. Anyway I _am_ helping you...pay attention to the link I gave you just now, it shows you how to write the rules properly. And make sure you use my version of JSFiddle to start from, not yours. After that, it's really quite simple. You just need to look more closely at what you're doing, and do basic research before you dash off some random code.

Comment: @ADyson  sorry for your valuable time to waste i know everyone time is valuable not only mine no need to be that much harsh if at all asked for help then

Comment: @ADyson however solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
     rules:{
      'email':{
       required:function(){
        return $('#uname').val().length > 0;
       }
      },
      'uname':{
       required:function(){
          return $('#email').val().length > 0;

       }
      }
     }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post"  id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="name"><b>Name</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" class="mygroup">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email"  id="email" class="mygroup">
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix">
       <button  id="submit" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>         
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need to check the length of the value because [the plugin provides a `:filled` selector for this.  `return $('#uname').is(':filled')`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="#" method="post"  id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label for="name"><b>Name</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" class="mygroup">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label for="email"><b>Email</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email"  id="email" class="mygroup">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <button  id="submit" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>         
                </div>
            </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('#uname').is(':filled');
            }

        },
        uname: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('#email').is(':filled');
            }       
        }              
    }      
});
});
```

Fiddle Link:  https://jsfiddle.net/rnmejfLy/